# Get the value of the adjacent cell if a cell contains a specific string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that would get me the value of the adjacent cell if any cell in the row matches the word "fizz" exactly.

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

```
1 | 
2 | 
3 | fizz
4 | 
5 | buzz
6 | fizz
7 |
```

and I'm looking for a formula that would return an array or a list similar to this if I searched for fizz

```
3
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula in `F2`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A8,$D$2=B2:B8,"None")
```

Or, for those who already have **[TAKE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/take-function-25382ff1-5da1-4f78-ab43-f33bd2e4e003)** may try:

```
=FILTER(TAKE(A2:B8,,1),D2=B2:B8)
```

Or, for those who are using earlier versions may try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,
AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
($D$2=$B$2:$B$8),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The above may need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` depending on your Excel Versions!